# why am I getting a MalformedURLException

Tags: java, android

I am not sure why this url is throwing a `MalformedURL` exception: `http%3A%2F%2Fapi.themoviedb.org%2F3%2Fsearch%2Fperson%3Fapi_key%3secret%26query%3Dchristopher_guest`

This is the url required by the api that I need to use. http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=secret&query=christopher_guest

I have been getting target host must not be **null** errors using this url then I changed my coded to what you are seeing below. Not sure whats going on here although I have heard urls that contain underscores dont validate outside of web browsers and cause these types of situations.

Any ideas around this?

This is where I build the url

```
package com.tot.tipofthetongue;

import android.widget.EditText;

public class getName {
static String nameOne = null;
static String nameTwo = null;

static StringBuilder personURLOne = new StringBuilder();
static StringBuilder personURLTwo = new StringBuilder();

public static String personURL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=secret&query=";

public static StringBuilder getName1(EditText searchOne){
    nameOne = searchOne.getText().toString();


    nameOne = nameOne.replace(" ", "_");


    personURLOne.append(personURL); 
    personURLOne = personURLOne.append(nameOne);



    return personURLOne;

}
```

And this is my jsonparser that I pass that url to.

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

static InputStream inputStream = null;
static JSONObject jObject = null;
static String jSon = "";
public String myURL;
String host;
HttpRequest request;
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Make HTTP Request
    try {
        //defaultHttpClient

        for(int i = 0; i < url.length; i++){
             myURL = url[0];
             myURL = URLEncoder.encode(myURL, "utf-8");
        }
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(myURL);

                //header
                httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");


                HttpResponse httpResponse = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpHost(new URL(myURL).getHost()), request);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }
                Log.d("JSON Contents", stringBuilder.toString());
                inputStream.close();

                jSon = stringBuilder.toString();


            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            //try to parse the string to JSON Object
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jSon);

            } catch (JSONException e){
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
            //return JSON String
            return jObject;
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried it without url encoding the url?

Answer (score 0):

Print the String you formed before final submission to form Uri. And attach this to your question. It would be much easier to answer.

Try using

```
HttpGet(URI uri)
```

instead of

```
HttpGet(String uri)
```

The reason is pretty simple. If you are using Uri, you will get immediately the Exception.

Hope this will help you to debug quickly.